# ModelState is cleared, but data still shows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When a user logs in, the normal thing to do is NOT give the password back. I am attempting this in MVC 5, and cannot make it happen. I have tried `model.PASSWORD = ""`, as well as `ModelState.Clear()`, but the data is still showing.

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(Login model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        User temp = await db.Users.Where(u => u.USERNAME == model.USERNAME).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if(temp != null) {
            try {
                if(Password.VerifyPass(model.PASSWORD, temp.PASSWORD)) {
                    LoginUser(temp);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "EMR");
                }
            } catch { }
        }
    }
    ModelState.Clear();
    model.PASSWORD = "";
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username/password is unknown, or model was invalid!");
    return View();
}
```

Model:

```
public class Login {

        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string USERNAME { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string PASSWORD { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.USERNAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.USERNAME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.USERNAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PASSWORD, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PASSWORD, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "password" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PASSWORD, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Upon looking at both the ModelState variable and the model variable in VisualStudio debug mode, they BOTH show the data as `""`. What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: How does your view code looks like ? How does your view model looks like ?

Comment: Thought I was missing something in there. Edited

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something obvious, but is there any reason that you are using @Html.EditorFor() over @Html.PasswordFor()?

Comment: I was unable to get `@class = "someCssClass"` with `@Html.PasswordFor()` to work until recently in another project, and hadn't gotten to changing it. Would that be a solution?

Comment: @JosephFerris After testing, it does work. would you mind making it an answer so that I can accept it as the simplest solution?

Comment: @CalebHuggins - Done.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had commented, one possible solution is to simply use @Html.PasswordFor().  This will render an input that is semantically correct for password input, which implicitly will hint for the browser to not autofill.  So, instead of @Html.EditorFor, try this:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.PASSWORD, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: what if i have any field other than password field how to clear its data?

Answer (score 1):

**You are not passed the model back to view after clear it**.

```
return View(model);
```

Still not working try as below.

```
var newModel = new Login { Password = "" };
ModelState.Clear();
return View(newModel);
```

Comment: The page still returns the previously entered password with either suggestions.

Comment: @CalebHuggins it looks like it is the browser who is rememberign the input fields values and populates them.

Comment: And now, after trying all of these, this is the only one that works. I might need to restart from scratch and rewrite everything.

Answer (score 1):

i think its due to the browser cashing, annotate login action with

```
[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
```

in addition to

```
return View(model);
```

Comment: Just the `[HttpGet]` or the `[HttpPost]` or both?

Comment: just `[HttpPost]`

Answer (score 1):

First decorate your password field with `Password` Datatype.

```
public class Login 
{    
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string USERNAME { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string PASSWORD { get; set; }        
}
```

And in the view, use the `PasswordFor` helper method.

```
@Html.PasswordFor(x=>x.PASSWORD)
```

With this, you do not need to explicitly set the password field to empty string. MVC will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

@CalebHuggins it looks like it is the browser who is rememberign the input fields values and populates them. You can try setting autocomplete attribute of your textboxes to "off" to avoid this.

Your model bound textbox may look like as following.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Something, new { autocomplete="off" } )
```

Thnaks and regards,
Chetan Ranpariya